# Can a country exit the TRIPS Agreement without exiting the WTO?

Tags: copyright, international, switzerland

Is it possible for a country to exit the TRIPS Agreement without exiting the WTO?

My question is basically whether or not the TRIPS Agreement is an essential part of the WTO or basically supplementary and optional for members.

Context:
I am Politically Active in Switzerland and want to figure out how I could reduce the Length of Copyright in Switzerland. I understand that we would first have to leave the Bern agreement but then there is also the TRIPS Agreement which limits how low I can go again. As far as I understand it those two agreements are pretty much it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRIPS is an essential part of the WTO. Article II(2) of the *[Marrakesh Agreement Establishing the World Trade Organization](https://www.wto.org/english/docs_e/legal_e/04-wto_e.htm)*:

> The agreements and associated legal instruments included in Annexes 1, 2 and 3 (hereinafter referred to as “Multilateral Trade Agreements”) are integral parts of this Agreement, binding on all Members.

TRIPS is part of Annex 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.